# Why does `sum` need `start` parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, to calculate sum of `timedelta` list, we need to write below:

```
sum(l, timedelta())
```

(l is list of instances of `timedelta`)

But we can calculate that without the `start` variable, like

```
l[0] + l[1] + l[2] + ...
```

Why the builtin `sum` function needs `start` value?

EDIT

If the `sum` function defined like

```
def sum2(l):
     return l[0] + (sum2(l[1:]) if len(l) > 2 else l[1])
```

and got `sum2([[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5]]) -> [1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 5]`
work well without start value.

I don't understand why sum don't work like this.

Comment: It does not need a start value. What made you think that?

Comment: `sum([1,1,1]) = 3`. `sum([], 10) = 10`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You have to specify a start value if your iterable contains items other than numbers, default start value is `0`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye What else would one want to `sum`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Timedeltas, apparently.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You could have an iterable of custom class objects that implement `__add__`. Everyone's mileage varies, don't make too many assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

`sum` is roughly equivalent to the following function:

```
def sum(iter, start=0):
   for element in iter:
       start = start + iter
   return start
```

This is the typical use case:

```
sum([1, 2, 3]) -> 6
```

But if you want to use it with an object which doesn't define integer addition you need to define the starting value. For example if you want to flatten a nested list.

```
sum([[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5]], []) -> [1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```